# Trouble referencing data member from member function

Tags: c++

Line 23 is:

```
List[i] = x;
```

When I try to compile:

```
g++ w3.cpp list.cpp line.cpp
list.cpp: In member function void List::set(int):
list.cpp:23:8: error: expected unqualified-id before [ token
```

Here's main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "list.h"

int main() {
    int no;
    List list;

    cout << "List Processor\n==============" << endl;
    cout << "Enter number of items : ";
    cin  >> no;

    list.set(no);
    list.display();
}
```

Here's list.h:

```
#include "line.h"
#define MAX_LINES 10
using namespace std;

struct List{
    private:
        struct Line line[MAX_LINES];
    public:
        void set(int no);
        void display() const;
};
```

Here's line.h:

```
#define MAX_CHARS 10
struct Line {
    private:
        int num;
        char numOfItem[MAX_CHARS + 1]; // the one is null byte
    public:
        bool set(int n, const char* str);
        void display() const;
};
```

Here's list.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
#include "list.h"
//#include "line.h" - commented this line because it was giving me a struct redefinition error

void List::set(int no) {

    int line;
    char input[20];

    if (no > MAX_LINES)
        no = MAX_LINES;

    for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {
    Line x;
        cout << "Enter line number : ";
        cin >> line;
        cout << "Enter line string : ";
        cin >> input;

        if (x.set(line, input)){
            List[i] = x;
            cout << "Accepted" << endl;
        }
        else
            cout << "Rejected" << endl;

    }
}

void List::display() const {



}
```

Comment: `List[i] = x;` I don't see `static operator[]` in your List class

Comment: In c++ what is the need of this : `char numOfItem[MAX_CHARS + 1];` you can use `string`

Comment: In my list struct I have a data member line, and it is an array. I want to access that data member and insert data into one of the indices. How do I reference line data member array of List struct?

Comment: You should add include guards to your header files, its not always as easy to solve include errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List` is a type name not a member. You probably meant

```
this->line[i] = x;
```

You must prefix with `this->` because `line` alone is ambiguous, because you have also

```
int line;
```

a few lines above (no pun intended).

To avoid naming conflicts and the use of `this->`, you could rename your variables, for example

```
struct List{
    private:
        struct Line lines[MAX_LINES];
    ...
};

void List::set(int no) {
    int lineno;
    ...
}
```

you can then assign without using `this->` or any other prefix

```
if (x.set(lineno, input)){
    lines[i] = x;
    cout << "Accepted" << endl;
}
```

Comment: That worked, I tried `*this` before haha, god I'm at terrible programmer. Thank you. What is the alternative way of doing it, not using `this->line[i]`?

Comment: @eveo If you want to avoid `this->`, please see updated answer.

Comment: I renamed variables and I tried `List.line[i] = x;` which gave me a plethora of errors.

Comment: @eveo There's no need to prefix with anything, if you renamed your variables non-ambiguous. If you must sometime prefix with a scope it is `List::` (double colon) instead of `List.`. See also my update.

Answer (score 1):

Let's understand the error message:

```
list.cpp: In member function 'void List::set(int)':
list.cpp:23:8: error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token
```

list.cpp line 23 is here:

```
List[i] = x;
```

And the complaint is:

```
expected [something] before '[' token
```

You are being told that the `List` object you designed doesn't support the `[ ]` syntax.

Comment: well explained error but add the ans. too +1.

Answer (score 1):

For this code to work:

```
List[i] = x;
```

Your class List hast to provide operator[] aka subscript operator:

```
class List {
public:
...
   Line &operator[]( int line );
...
};
```

This is an example, it can return const reference or return value, be a const method etc depends on your program.

Comment: i'm writing my ans. and your comes. :) . so that operator is called `subscripting` operator. So add it in your ans. +1